# Set Json type in message GRPC

Tags: json, grpc

This is my message:

```
message ResponseMessage {
    bool success = 1;
    string message = 2;
    uint32 status_code = 3;
    ? data = 4;
    repeated string error = 5;
}
```

My problem is that because of using a database, there is no data type specified for the data, and the type is inside the code as an object. Now I do not know how to keep json data in grpc

Comment: Why not just keep it as a string?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use the [google.protobuf.Struct](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Struct) type. As example:

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message ResponseMessage {
    bool success = 1;
    string message = 2;
    uint32 status_code = 3;
    google.protobuf.Struct data = 4;
    repeated string error = 5;
}
```

Remember to add the google path in the import statement of the protoc complile script.

Comment: Hi how to use google.protobuf.Struct  in php.

Comment: You can take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/php) or [here](https://www.filippotoso.com/sviluppo/convertire-googleprotobufstruct-in-un-array-php.php)